# Downscaled Bitmap from View

Tags: android, android-bitmap

What would be most efficient way to get downscaled Bitmap from the view?

before I was using this code :

```
 rootView.isDrawingCacheEnabled = true
                val drawingCache = rootView.drawingCache
                val bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(
                        drawingCache,
                        drawingCache.width / 2,
                        drawingCache.height / 2,
                        false
                )
                rootView.isDrawingCacheEnabled = false
```

but `drawingCache` is deprecated now.

Comment: I use same way, and it is the only way I found - using drawing cache

Comment: yes, but drawingCache is deprecated now.

Comment: Have you read why was it deprecated, and how can be replaced? https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getDrawingCache()